# Mutex between reads and writes

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, mutex

I am using a mutex for the critical section. I have a design constraint that,
1) If 2 reads occur in 2 different thread, then critical section should be available for both. 
2) If there is a write happening, then read on other thread should be blocked
3) If there is a read happening, then write on other thread should be blocked.

I dont know to do this with Createmutex, openmutex, waitforsingleobject and releasemutex apis.

Comment: If you want a within-process lock in Windows you should use critical section rather than mutex. But you want a reader-writer lock anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [Reader-Writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock). There are some implementations of it on the internet, for example [this one](http://www.glennslayden.com/code/win32/reader-writer-lock).

Comment: One caution:  Reader-Writer locks *cannot* be fair.  You should also look at the reader-writer lock package carefully - if it allows the conversion of a shared lock to an exclusive lock, you should avoid it - there's no way of implementing shared->exclusive without introducing the possibility of a deadlock.  If the package author left in a shared->exclusive API, it means they really didn't think about the synchronization issues inherent in reader-writer locks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link to see whether this native windows api meets your requirements:

[Slim Reader/Writer (SRW) Locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904937%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your synchronization/critical section issue is limited to a single process and many threads, i recommend you use [Critical Section Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of [Mutex Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You have a couple of examples on the pages linked from msdn. Read the linked msdn pages and if you have the basic concurrency synchronization concepts and the required Windows Api knowledge under your belt, you should be rolling in no time, if not read around. There's nothing that special about Mutexes and Critical Sections from the api standpoint.